# How to download a file from an url using Powershell script and enforce tls 1.1

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl, tls1.2

We are downloading a file from a vendor site and they recently upgraded from tls 1.0 to 1.1. How to download the file using Powershell  script and enforce tls 1.1
Below code used to work until they upgraded. Please advise.

```
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.DownloadFile("https://www.contoso.com/file","C:\path\file")
```

Comment: Please post the error you receive when running the commands.

Comment: `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls11'`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this fixed my issue. Thank you Jessen.

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls11'
```

Comment: As a value vor the property, use whatever protocol version is required by the remote host (i.e. `'Tls12'`)

You can get teh host's version by retrieving the certificate:
`openssl s_client -connect {HOSTNAME}:{PORT} -showcerts`
(found here: https://superuser.com/a/176721/206783)